# Transform vector of boost::shared_ptr using boost::bind and boost::static_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, boost, stl, shared-ptr, boost-bind

I have a std::vector of Boost shared pointers to objects, and would like to get a vector of shared pointers to the same objects casted down to a more specific type:

```
//using boost::shared_ptr, std::vector;
vector<shared_ptr<A> > originalVec;
vector<shared_ptr<B> > targetVec( originalVec.size() ); // B extends A
```

For a single element `shared_ptr<A> elem`, it is possible to cast it using `boost::static_pointer_cast<B>(elem)`, whose syntax is reproduced below (from [Boost shared_ptr doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)):

```
template<class T, class U>
shared_ptr<T> static_pointer_cast(shared_ptr<U> const & r); // never throws
```

I don't know how to use it with `std::transform`. Mi tries include:

```
//using boost::bind, boost::static_pointer_cast
transform( originalVec.begin(), originalVec.end(), targetVec.begin(), bind( static_pointer_cast<B>, _1) )
transform( originalVec.begin(), originalVec.end(), targetVec.begin(), bind( static_pointer_cast<B,A>, _1) )
```

Getting in both cases a `"no matching function for call to bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, boost::arg<1>& )"`

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT:**
The problem could be related with an ambiguity, since a similar function template is defined for intrusive pointer class, with syntax:

```
template<class T, class U>
intrusive_ptr<T> static_pointer_cast(intrusive_ptr<U> const & r); // never throws
```

The question, in this case, is how to specify the type of the first argument so that the compiler knows which method to select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can usually tell the compiler which overload you want by specifying the type of the function pointer you want e.g.

```
typedef shared_ptr<B>(*func_type)(const shared_ptr<A>&);

transform( originalVec.begin(), originalVec.end(), targetVec.begin(), bind( (func_type)static_pointer_cast<B,A>, _1) );
```

But in cases where you get this sort of error from an overloaded function that can't be disambiguated, my preferred solution is often to provide a custom functor that does the call, so that overload resolution is done by the compiler, and you don't have to select an overload e.g.

```
struct Downcast {
  shared_ptr<B> operator()(const shared_ptr<A>& p) const
  { return shared_pointer_cast<B>(p); }
};

transform( originalVec.begin(), originalVec.end(), targetVec.begin(), Downcast() );
```

Comment: Here we are in the second case: the ambiguity cannot be resolved.
I was using transform to avoid writing a loop... and in that sense, having to create a functor spoils the conciseness and simplicity I had in mind (even more code than the loop!!). It's a pity we don't have lambda expressions in C++98 :P
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ooook, no other satisfactory solutions, so I accept yours. Finally used a simple "for" loop. Aaaah C++, you merciless b**ch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you got that error with your second try, because that one should've worked.

However, there is a possibility you'll overrun the bounds of `targetVec` if it is empty because simply passing an iterator to `transform` is not enough, you need to `push_back` the result of the cast into `targetVec`. This can be done easily by passing a [`back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to `transform`.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A>> original;
    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<B>> target;

    original.push_back( boost::make_shared<B>() );

    boost::transform( original,
                      std::back_inserter( target ),
                      boost::bind( boost::static_pointer_cast<B, A>, _1 ) );

    // OR
    std::transform( original.begin(), 
                    original.end(),
                    std::back_inserter( target ),
                    boost::bind( boost::static_pointer_cast<B, A>, _1 ) );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm particularly annoyed with the second try not working.
Thank you for your suggestion, but it is not the case: I just forgot to say that the second array has enough space reserved --declared as vector<shared_ptr<B> > targetVec( originalVec.size() );